# Why is my BASH compiler skipping over my code?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I wrote a `for` loop to get the number of tools that haven't been installed. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIALOG_INSTALLED=$(which dialog)
BREW_INSTALLED=$(which brew)
TELNET_INSTALLED=$(which telnet)

UNINSTALLED_TOOLS=0

for installed_for in $DIALOG_INSTALLED $BREW_INSTALLED $TELNET_INSTALLED; do
    if [[ -z $installed_for ]]; then
        let "$UNINSTALLED_TOOLS+=1"
    fi
done

echo $UNINSTALLED_TOOLS
```

My problem is that when I go to run the code, `$UNINSTALLED_TOOLS` is still equal to 0. To find the root of the issue, `$UNINSTALLED_TOOLS=3` before and after the `for` loop. Both of these adjustments changed the final value of `$UNINSTALLED_TOOLS` to 3. Now I know that the issue lies within the `for` loop. It's as if the code is skipping over the `for` loop. I don't get any syntax errors so I'm very confused.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `dialog` is not found. After variable substitution, you get:

```
for installed_for in /usr/local/bin/brew /usr/local/bin/telnet; do
```

So `$installed_for` never has an opportunity to be an empty string. Once you make `for` loop with the empty string, your `let` is incorrect, too, since after the substitution you have

```
let 0+=1
```

which makes no sense. So:

```
DIALOG_INSTALLED=$(which dialog)
BREW_INSTALLED=$(which brew)
TELNET_INSTALLED=$(which telnet)

INSTALLED_ARRAY=("$DIALOG_INSTALLED" "$BREW_INSTALLED" "$TELNET_INSTALLED")
UNINSTALLED_TOOLS=0

for installed_for in "${INSTALLED_ARRAY[@]}"; do
    if [[ -z "$installed_for" ]]; then
        let UNINSTALLED_TOOLS+=1
    fi
done
echo "$UNINSTALLED_TOOLS"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for installed_for in $DIALOG_INSTALLED $BREW_INSTALLED $TELNET_INSTALLED; do
```

This isn't a loop over 3 elements; it's a loop over however many words the variables `$DIALOG_INSTALLED $BREW_INSTALLED $TELNET_INSTALLED` expand to.  So for instance if you had `/usr/bin/dialog`, `/bin/telnet`, but `brew` was uninstalled, then the `for` will be a loop over 2 elements, just as if you had typed

```
for installed_for in /usr/bin/dialog  /bin/telnet; do
```

In particular, `[[ -z $installed_for ]]` will never be true.

You probably want to quote them, so that if any of them is empty, the `for` loop still iterates over it as an empty string:

```
for installed_for in "$DIALOG_INSTALLED" "$BREW_INSTALLED" "$TELNET_INSTALLED"; do
```

Also, `let "$UNINSTALLED_TOOLS+=1"` is wrong.  It expands `$UNINSTALLED_TOOLS` before evaluating the arithmetic, so it becomes something like `let 0+=1` which is invalid.  It should instead be `let "UNINSTALLED_TOOLS+=1"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to count the uninstalled tools you can do something like this

```
w() { which -s "$1"; echo $?; }
uninstalled_tools=$(( $(w dialog) + $(w brew) + $(w telnet) ))
```

No loop is needed. Just make the function echo the value and sum.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off with a loop like this:

```
for i in dialog brew telnet; do
    command -v "$i" &>/dev/null ||
    ((++missing))
done

echo "${missing:-0}" missing dependencies
```

You can add logic for error messages etc.